# how to handle errors in yii

Tags: exception, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am working on an application using yii. I have an action let `acmanageappointments/index`. I have defined its rule as follow

```
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','create','update','delete','updatestatus'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
```

and its action is as follow :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        $user_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();   
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = 'user_id='.$user_id;
        $count=AcAppointments::model()->count($criteria);
        $pages=new CPagination($count);

        //results per page 
        $pages->pageSize=10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);
        $AllAppointments = AcAppointments::model()->findAll($criteria);

        // Applying Global Date Time Format 
        $condition = array('user_id' => $user_id);
        $DTFormat = CalendarSettings::model()->findByAttributes($condition);

        $this->render('index',array(
                'AllAppointments' => $AllAppointments,
                'pages' => $pages,
                'DTFormat' => $DTFormat,
        ));


    }
```

This action can only be accessed with authenticated persons. when I am logged in then this function is working properly. but when I am logged out and executing this action then it gives `CDbException`. How can I handle this exception, and when the user is logged out and if he is trying to access this url then he should be redirected on login page . How can I do this ?

**update** : Here is my accessrules :

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','create','update','delete','updatestatus'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

and here is the error :

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: What other access rules have you defined?

Comment: no i havent defined any other rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As topher mentioned in comments, you need a `filters` method.

Make sure you have this in your controller, else your access rules will do nothing:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', 
    );
}
```

If it works, give his answer credit when he updates it with this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define another rule that will ensure that non-authenticated users are denied access. This must be the last rule.

```
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
    'actions'=>array('index','create','update','delete','updatestatus'),
    'users'=>array('@'),
),
array('deny',
    'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

Comment: thnx topher, I have done that also, now I am getting the same problem

Comment: while surfing I seen that I have to remove yii_debug from index.php, whats taht exactly

Comment: Could you post your `accessRules` method?

Comment: public function accessRules()
 {
  return array(
   array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
    'actions'=>array('view','admin'),
    'users'=>array('admin'),
   ),
   array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
    'actions'=>array('index','create','update','delete','updatestatus'),
    'users'=>array('@'),
   ),
   array('deny',  // deny all users
    'users'=>array('*'),
   ),
  );
 }

Comment: It's hard to read in its current format. Update the question with this and your CDbException error message

Comment: ok. The `accessrules()` seem to be fine. Do you have a `filters` method? Also what is the browser url when the Exception is thrown?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24618/discussion-between-topher-and-lord-linus)

Answer (score 1):

You can have an errorHandler setting in your config file "main.php"

```
'components'=>array(
    ...............
    ...............
    'errorHandler'=>array(
    // use 'site/error' action to display errors
    'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    ...............
    ...............
)
```

this will redirect all the exceptions to the provided URL site/error in this case.

Comment: THANKS ankur ji bt, the thing which I was forgetting is the one which Willem Renzema has explained ...

Answer (score 0):

Check value $user_id. if you are not logged in, you get empty $user_id

```
$user_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();   
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 'user_id='.$user_id;
```

When you execute with this criteria you got SQL error